# javascript api popup window not appearing on feature

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I'm using the javascript api and the popup window is not opening adjacent to the clicked feature,  but is opening up on the other side of the map.  Any ideas why it would be doing this or how I might correct?

my code for the pop up and feature layer:

```
 var popUpTemplateLU = new PopupTemplate({
          fieldInfos: [
          {
              label: "Sheet:",
              fieldName: "SHEET",
              visible: true
          },
          {
              label: "Reach:",
              fieldName: "REACH",
              visible: true
          }
 ]
      });

  var flLine = new      FeatureLayer("http://www.XXX/MapServer/0", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
          infoTemplate: popUpTemplateLU,
          outFields: ["*"]
      });
```

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

I had a content pane on the right region with lots of text in it.  When I removed that content pane the pop now appears next to the feature.  This isnt really an answer, but a work around.  I moved the text to a pop up, and have more room for the map